Texstudio not compiling bibliography (biblatex, biber vs bibtex)
I am trying to use biblatex on TexStudio and it is simply not compiling the bibliography part at all when I use bibtex instead of biber for the "default bibliography tool." If at all possible I want to still use bibtex to compile instead of swapping between biber and bibtex as the compiling tool, because some of my files have bibliographies in bibtex. I was under the impression that you could use bibtex or biber to run biblatex, so I am confused why this is failing in TexStudio.
It must be a problem with the TexStudio setup, because using the same tex file and the same bib file on Overleaf goes through perfectly fine.
Here is the code for the tex file:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%opening
\title{\texttt{Biblatex} MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

First source to be cited \parencite{TaoBook} 

\printbibliography


\end{document}

Here is the code for the bib file:
@book {TaoBook,
    AUTHOR = {Tao, Terence},
    TITLE = {Topics in random matrix theory},
    SERIES = {Graduate Studies in Mathematics},
    PUBLISHER = {American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI},
    YEAR = {2012},
}

Here are the TexStudio settings:

Here is a photo of the tex file compiled correctly in Overleaf:

Here is a photo of the tex file compiled incorrectly in TexStudio:


This output means that you only compiled the LaTeX engine once and that you didn't compile Biber. If this is the case, you need to go to the settings > "Build" [now you are in the same window of the screenshot] > configure bottom in the "Default compiler" line. At this point, a window will open. You have to select the engines that you need to run for each compilation. Just add biber and then, again, pdfLaTeX. See if this works.

Technically speaking you can still use BibTeX instead of Biber with biblatex. But if you do so, you need to tell biblatex explicitly about this by passing the backend=bibtex, option. You will also lose out on many of biblatex's more prominent features (among which are proper Unicode support, dynamical data manipulation, support for multiple independent bibliographies). So using BibTeX with biblatex is really not recommended.
Most editors let you switch the bibliography tool pretty easily (see Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations), so you don't really lose a lot if you configure your editor to run Biber for you, you can easily switch back.
Many editors also allow you to change the bibliography tool locally for a document using "magic commands". See When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?. So this could be an option as well. Set up your editor to use the backend (Biber or BibTeX) you use more often and then use magic commands for the occasional document that uses the other.
Finally, you can also look into just using latexmk and you will almost never have to worry about which tool to call again. latexmk can automatically detect if BibTeX or Biber needs to be called. (Your document compiles fine on Overleaf, because Overleaf uses latexmk behind the scenes and latexmk automatically runs Biber as required for your example document.)
